# how to determine bounds for area polar coordinates

Tags: calculus

I've found the correct graph, and know how to integrate to find the area, I just don't know how to find the bounds to integrate with to find the area

[image]

Comment: Any interval of length $2\pi$, since then the full curve is traced out. Might as well pick a nice one.

Comment: @André Nicolas but how do I find the lower and upper bounds to integrate to find the area?

Comment: Lower $0$, upper $2\pi$. Or if you prefer, lower, $-\pi$,  upper $\pi$. Or else find the area of half, and double.  I take it you know we are integrating $\frac{1}{2}(2+2\cos\theta)^2$.

Comment: @André Nicolas but how do you figure out the bounds? Should a certain theta value start repeating the pattern, as if starting at 0 again? How did u get 0 to 2pi ?

Comment: Yes, things start again at $2\pi$, if we integrate from $0$ to $4\pi$ we will trace out the curve twice, get twice the right area.

Comment: You've drawn the graph of $r=2+2\color{red}{\sin}\theta$. If you rotate this by 90 degrees clockwise you will get the graph of $r=2+2\cos\theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the boundary is traced as the polar angle, $\theta$, makes one revolution (i.e., extends a full $2\pi$ radians).

Then, the area of a segment traced by a differential angle $d\theta$ is the area of a "differential triangle" and is given by $\frac12 \times r \times (r\,d\theta)$.

Putting it all together, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac12 (r) (rd\theta)&=2\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac12 r^2d\theta\\\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\pi}2(1+\cos \theta)^2\,d\theta
\end{align}$$

Comment: is that a double integral? We didn't learn/use that yet